# Can't copy a pen

Tags: css

I'm trying to put this http://codepen.io/digitalcraft/pen/yydpbB in my website but I can't figure out how. I tried to copy all the html, css and java but doesn't work, then I tried to copy the essential parts of html, without the **`<h4>DC YOLO BOX v1</h4>`** and copying the css by fixing the brackets but nothing to do, why?

```js
$(document).mousemove(rotateScene);

function rotateScene(e) {
 var horizontal = e.pageX / $(document).width();
 var vertical = e.pageY / $(document).height(); 
 $('.panel').css({
  '-webkit-transform': 'rotateX(' + (10 - (vertical * 17)) + 'deg) rotateY(' + (-20 + (horizontal * 40)) + 'deg)'
 });
}
```

```css
html{
 height:100%;
 min-height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
    }
    body{font: 14px/21px Monaco, sans-serif;
  color: #999;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  height:100%;
  min-height: 100%;
    }
    
    $color: cyan;
$spectrum: 15%;
$duration: 8s;
    
    .scene {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  perspective: 600;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;}
    
    .panel {
    width: 320px;
    height: 240px;
    background: #c5c5c5;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 30px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    /*Start hardware acceleration*/
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    animation: colorfader $duration ease-in-out infinite;}
    
    h1 {
      font-family: "Lato",sans-serif;
      font-size:60px;
      font-weight:300;
      color:rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
      text-align:center;
      margin-top:33%;
      }
```

```html
<div class="scene">
  <div class="panel"><h1>YOLO</h1></div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't used a library give link to the  jquery try something like this

```
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

at the head section

Answer (score 0):

You need to add html.

If you want it to be fully functional, you need to add:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Your Title</title>
    <style>
html{
    height:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
    }
    body{font: 14px/21px Monaco, sans-serif;
  color: #999;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  height:100%;
  min-height: 100%;
    }

    $color: cyan; /* <- You need to change from whatever preprocessor you're using to css*/ 
$spectrum: 15%; /* <- You need to change from whatever preprocessor you're using to css*/ 
$duration: 8s; /* <- You need to change from whatever preprocessor you're using to css*/ 

    .scene {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  perspective: 600;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;}

    .panel {
    width: 320px;
    height: 240px;
    background: #c5c5c5;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 30px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    /*Start hardware acceleration*/
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    animation: colorfader $duration ease-in-out infinite;} /* <- You need to change from whatever preprocessor you're using to css*/ 

    h1 {
      font-family: "Lato",sans-serif;
      font-size:60px;
      font-weight:300;
      color:rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
      text-align:center;
      margin-top:33%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="scene">
      <div class="panel"><h1>YOLO</h1></div>
    </div>
  </body>
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).mousemove(rotateScene);

function rotateScene(e) {
    var horizontal = e.pageX / $(document).width();
    var vertical = e.pageY / $(document).height();  
    $('.panel').css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotateX(' + (10 - (vertical * 17)) + 'deg) rotateY(' + (-20 + (horizontal * 40)) + 'deg)'
    });
}
</script>
</html>
```

You seem to be using a pre-processor instead of *css*.

The `style` tag inside head contains *css*, and the jquery right below the closing `body` tag contains js.

The jquery library is added right above your js. The reason to that is loading time and performance.